# Limit of the ratio of two matrix expansions

Tags: matrices, limits

With $M$, $N$ and $W_r$ non-zero (invertible) square matrices, how can one calculate the following limit

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left[ I -  \frac{M \left(\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \epsilon^{-r} W_{r} \right) M}{I - M \left( \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \epsilon^{-r} W_{r} \right)  N} \right],
\end{equation}
where $0 < \epsilon \ll 1$ and $I$ is the identity matrix.